comment faire en latex pour avoir la même presentation
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{machin}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\fancyfoot[L]{truc}
\fancyfoot[R]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\section{Ma section}
Blabla
\end{document}


Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title. Besides, please write in English.

In case you prefer to ask in French: https://texnique.fr/osqa/

I see no question at all.

Same presentation as what? La même présentation que quoi?

Off-topic: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} has been the default for at least 5 years by now and thus needn't be run unless your TeX distribution hasn't been updated for that length of time.
